# Corrupt frames error while evaluating vmaf

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg with libvmaf support. Attached is the uncut ffmpeg output which will help you with ffmpeg versions and other information. I am facing following error intermittently, also in my case source and encoded videos are stored in s3 bucket and I am inputting them to ffmpeg using s3 presigned HTTP URL.

Reason for URL is, I am running ffmpeg on AWS Batch containers which has storage limits, hence I cant download file on server, and thats why I am using URL

```
Corrupt input packet in stream 0\n[h264 @ 0x4745e00] Invalid NAL unit size (21976 > 13373).\n[h264 @ 0x4745e00] Error splitting the input into NAL units.


    {"level":"debug","time":"2020-10-29T18:50:05Z","message":"Command err: ffmpeg version N-98384-g3b8d5bcc31 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)\n  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/usr/local/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-libzimg --enable-libopus --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265\n  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100\n  libavcodec     58. 93.104 / 58. 93.104\n  libavformat    58. 47.100 / 58. 47.100\n  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100\n  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100\n  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100\n  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100\n  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a':\n  Metadata:\n    major_brand     : isom\n    minor_version   : 512\n    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41\n    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100\n  Duration: 00:45:41.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 268 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 266 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    : VideoHandler\nInput #1, mxf, from 'http://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/b856b6ff-5f57-4f7a-b62b-2a851cb86eaf/MasterMezzanine.mxf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1a3314912af2a2eb1558362d346b2498f9e8b00933308eddeb4a31fc8701bee7':\n  Metadata:\n    operational_pattern_ul: 060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010900\n    uid             : e54552c8-1ffc-4378-accb-f5c5f12843c7\n    generation_uid  : 0377fe71-cf93-4248-9f55-e6a7d042ff21\n    modification_date: 2020-07-17T19:05:44.524000Z\n    company_name    : Elemental Technologies, Inc\n    product_name    : Server\n    product_version : 2.17.0.602675\n    product_uid     : 060e2b34-0101-0101-0f45-544953657276\n    application_platform: libMXF (Linux 64-bit)\n    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D2013000000E4B5112668944A2EB48B1CA686F0EFDC\n    timecode        : 00:00:00:00\n  Duration: 00:45:41.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 35163 kb/s\n    Stream #1:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 35000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc\n    Metadata:\n      file_package_umid: 

rframe=44294 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:31.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44302 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:32.08 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44306 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:32.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44311 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:32.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44315 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:32.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44320 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:32.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44328 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:33.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44336 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:33.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44341 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:33.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44345 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:33.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44350 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:34.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44356 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:34.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44364 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:34.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44369 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:34.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44376 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:35.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44383 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:35.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44386 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:35.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44392 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:35.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44399 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:35.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44404 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:36.16 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44413 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:36.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44416 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:36.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44420 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:36.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44426 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:37.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \r[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3e2af80] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 160023600).\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3e2af80] stream 0, offset 0x36e308b: partial file\nframe=44433 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:37.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: corrupt input packet in stream 0\n[h264 @ 0x4745e00] Invalid NAL unit size (21976 > 13373).\n[h264 @ 0x4745e00] Error splitting the input into NAL units.\nhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: Invalid data found when processing input\nframe=44437 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:37.48 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: Invalid data found when processing input\n    Last message repeated 5 times\nframe=44443 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:37.72 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: Invalid data found when processing input\n    Last message repeated 7 times\nError while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input\nhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: Invalid data found when processing input\n    Last message repeated 1 times\nframe=44452 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:38.08 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rhttp://packaged-vod-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vmaf-compare/155418_1/Bitmovin/mp4/video_1.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYOHIUN2NFPHIZTO7%2F20201029%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201029T165637Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEAIaDM44L40R8xFOdOiOsSKMBOsKsGIulSEJb56GhTQWhF63T%2F1rRNvb%2Fjxl%2BgKBdWJVctbY18T1FcddIP7GkSO0atB%2FwVUZibLhul3Hvz55ofqmx7gfx6ezW9rYWsdHIvwe1TTP3LME2IzaHULs9ag%2FVTnNxXEYR%2BDkhA8wc2Q936axVDRXgoz5h%2FeusuWF6aRctns%2Bj7BLltZz86Flu%2FdqLp%2F1D3Kq1HdiBvT1eBZ%2B7ibAFLTGAbqAtKT79djwj62aiCYUeqHXtUhz7aM81n09fXBPi0bkc5hlCon%2BdqWE2rkuXfEV47Xc7u6ZuCtBB%2F2SjVpRZMiif4%2Fuz2OaLdEah1SrsWnqWDF75p96WtO7ObbtayoaGcEgWOQ4OxNaQyoDV8B8OveUs%2BNRmSa7vJYFOg0JGfMeBJx8B%2FDe8ED970utUbtp7r4vp1FCwhcDZ0RiSPfvR52dOPMQ6gZ4UaZ9CYcQ1um0vZwqvh2Ij8eveooFEEQoeL5VPwSkrZtFKK5k%2BOqhmce5oFlhHnKxhqeBA5jPxnPyVTQrKlfy7%2BFaqSNUEdNnUodRw8jrnJHUEJ3oB9xxgiWKdtQSQXldnEZxKM%2FbIcCLbZYZlj4t94oDeNiLjhe7sFAtVQ4A93OgQZqBARYp70jfIVmZIszW%2B0ko7PgrrAGqloN4Jf8rdR2abZ9APG2U5QEV0BQt1SkJxuS7YYWpExIFhoe2xpzRKMDo6%2FwFMjefaPrCZ1hL0lfn0UfzdrpdetJCwrF1f4NJ4KKQqS3SR0Vv9pFYH8qRKx1csl6XbUbi41TFxbhz&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=70cee7ad192c375364be2da79c689c6230dba92ff27ca87cbaf250660eaf679a: Invalid data found when processing input\nframe=44457 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:38.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44464 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:38.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44467 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:38.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44478 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:39.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44482 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:39.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44489 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:39.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44495 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:39.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44500 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:40.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44508 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:40.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44513 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:29:40.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.42x    \rframe=44520 fps= 10 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=
```

Comment: *stream 0, offset 0x36e308b: partial file*  --> the MP4 is truncated.

Comment: Ok i understand but why this happens only intermittently...i mean i have out of 10 atleast 7 times when this command succesfully works...is it something to do with s3 presigned url...does ffmpeg has some limitation in terms of vmaf calculation on streaming file...is there a way we can ensure the command never fails

Comment: Copy the file locally or host it elsewhere or debug why S3 reads fails.

Comment: @gyan thanks for advice. one quick thing does the above erroe means that there was  problem in decoding or vmaf was not able to process the decoded frames?

Comment: Since the file is truncated, frames were missing, so neither a decoding issue nor a VMAF issue.